# No audio after new updates

Tags: sound, 13.04, modules

Yesterday after new updates my sound is gone.

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             28152  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
bnep                   18036  2 
rfcomm                 42641  0 
bluetooth             228619  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17500  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36913  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    78399  1 
snd_hda_intel          39619  0 
snd_hda_codec         136453  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               80847  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13056  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13202  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40513  1 uvcvideo
videodev              129260  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97451  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_timer              29425  1 snd_pcm
snd                    68876  7 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
coretemp               13355  0 
kvm_intel             132891  0 
kvm                   443165  1 kvm_intel
soundcore              12680  1 snd
microcode              22881  0 
lpc_ich                17061  0 
intel_ips              17978  0 
psmouse                95870  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
i915                  600351  3 
drm_kms_helper         49394  1 i915
ndiswrapper           283323  0 
drm                   286313  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei                    41158  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
topstar_laptop         12837  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 topstar_laptop
video                  19390  1 i915
mac_hid                13205  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12540  0 
ahci                   25731  3 
libahci                31364  1 ahci
usbhid                 47074  0 
hid                   101002  2 hid_generic,usbhid
r8169                  67446  0
```

My module is gone too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the next command had fixed the problem:

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```